# form creation help in delphi

Tags: delphi

I am using Delphi 7 and trying to create Delphi application having 5 buttons on Main Form. Each button click will display another form with some components on it. The most components on subform for all button clicks are same. Which will be better way to do:

1. to create new form on each click and and destroy it when it closed

   or
2. to create one form once and use the same form for others (using directly `ShowModal`)?

But the problem in 2nd option is when I show that subform on 2nd time then the values of form remains same as when entered first time. Any solution to refresh it quickly?? or any other solution to display form?

Comment: It sounds like you already know the solution, option 1. What's wrong with option 1. Using fresh instances is always to be preferred in comparison with using stale instances.

Comment: Provide some code you've already done!

Comment: thats true.. but i just want to know any better solution to this.. If the components on the forms are same then creating it on each click is not gud solution i guess. thanks.

Comment: @Naren No, creating a new instance each time is an excellent solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that these forms are already auto-created when you add them to your app. You only need to create one of these, and remove its auto-creation.

Go to Project > Options > Forms tab and look at the list of 'Auto-Create forms'. Remove your sub-form from this list (adding it to the list on the right of 'available forms').

Now you don't need to create 5 different forms if you are showing them as modal, especially. You just need one...

**Unit1**

5 `TButton` controls, all sharing the same `ButtonClick` event (for this example) and whatever other controls you wish...

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    Button3: TButton;
    Button4: TButton;
    Button5: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

uses
  Unit2;

procedure TForm1.ButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  F: TForm2; //Declaration of the form
begin
  F:= TForm2.Create(nil); //Creation of the form
  try
    F.ShowModal;
  finally
    F.Free; //Destruction of the form
  end;
end;

end.
```

Note that I never once refer to the name `Form2`. Instead, I temporarily declare `F: TForm2` just for the duration that I need it. If it wasn't going to be modal, you would need a far different approach.

Answer (score -2):

If all buttons are doing same, put that subform to auto create list. Define a function in subform's unit file with name "resetField". Before calling showModal function, call that resetField function of that subform. So, the form before in its default values everytime.

Comment: Wow, it seems like we both gave completely opposite yet possibly equally effective answers :P

Comment: -1 Much easier to create a new instance each time and have the initialisation done in the constructor.

Comment: I don't think creating a new instance everytime button is clicked better. While creating a new form, there are lots of system calls. But to show an already created form needs less.

Comment: Yeah after thinking about that option, I realized it's a total mess and almost defeats the whole purpose of implementing OOP applications. Also, think about how long it takes your application to load as opposed to how long it takes each little window to load. Do you want a bunch of windows to load when your application starts, or do you want them to load when the user tries to use it?

Comment: Well, if there are 5 buttons, suppose at least 5 of them will be pressed once. Instead of making user to wait each time when the button is clicked, let him/her to wait once. That's better I think.

Comment: @johnny: thanks. how to store default values?  or its like setting it manually? like edit1.text=''?

Comment: Depending on the purposes, in many cases, it may be even heavier to set default values than it is to just create a new form. Imagine a form with just 1 `TMemo` control. But this `TMemo` has a default value with over 5,000 characters.

Comment: @Johnny Creating and showing new forms from an already running app, in response to user input, is instantaneous to the user.